# I don't find already installed packages and I'm not able to reinstall..why?

Tags: r

I've always used ggplot2... now R didn't found anymore ggplot2.. so I tried to reinstall the package.. withour success... why??? What should I do?

Also I'm not able to install other packages like lattice extra..

Thank you!

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/vale/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
        binary source needs_compilation
ggplot2  3.1.1  3.2.1             FALSE

installing the source package ‘ggplot2’

provo con l'URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.2.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3204655 bytes (3.1 MB)
downloaded 3.1 MB

* installing *source* package 'ggplot2' ...
** package 'ggplot2' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called 'colorspace'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'ggplot2'
* removing 'C:/Users/vale/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/ggplot2'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/vale/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/ggplot2'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\vale\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\vale\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgHJKyj/downloaded_packages/ggplot2_3.2.1.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\vale\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgHJKyj\downloaded_packages’
> library(ggplot2)
Errore: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘colorspace’
> install.packages("latticeExtra")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/vale/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘latticeExtra’ is not available (for R version 3.4.3)
> library(latticeExtra)
Carico il pacchetto richiesto: RColorBrewer
```

Comment: `R version 3.4.3`  !!??  The current version is 3.6.3   The messages are telling you that not all dependencies are available for your old copy of R.  I would suggest updating R.   ggplot2 should be available for the current version of R.

Comment: This worked!!!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Install the missing colorspace package by executing the following line in R:

```
install.packages("colorspace")
```